# Print to Win32 screen

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, printing

I want to print to a win32 screen using TextOut function when i send a WM_PAINT message, i am an ASM coder and ive been fighting a lot to understand typecast on C++.

In theory i need a global buffer that store mine strings and display the lines one by one when i get a WM_PAINT message, problem is i read that is no good to use global variables. So is there another approach to print to screen without using a global buffer for store mine strings?.

Also here is mine another problem:

```
PrintLines *PaintArray[MAX_PRINT_LINES];
int CurrentLine;

    void Print(HWND hWnd, int rgb, const char* string, ...)
    {
        MSG msg;
        char buff[MAX_LINE_CHARS];
        if (CurrentLine >= MAX_PRINT_LINES)
        {
            CurrentLine = 0;
            memset (*PaintArray, NULL, sizeof PaintArray);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        }
        va_list argList;
        va_start(argList, string);
        PaintArray[CurrentLine]->stringlen = vsprintf(buff, string, argList);
        va_end (argList);
        PaintArray[CurrentLine]->rgb = rgb;
        CurrentLine+=1;
        msg.hwnd = hWnd;
        msg.message = WM_PAINT;
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

When i debug the call to vsprintf i see:

```
00412AD3   8B15 98B34100    MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[CurrentLine]
00412AD9   8B0495 20B34100  MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX*4+PaintArray]
00412AE0   50               PUSH EAX
00412AE1   FF15 6CC44100    CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&MSVCR110D.vsprintf>>; MSVCR110.vsprintf
```

The **EDX*4+Offset PainArray** tells me its an array that point to the actual class array i want (wich is good), but when debugging its initialized to 0. How can i initialize it?

Also how i can make compiler do this:

```
MOV Edx, CurrentLine
Imul Edx, Edx, SizeOf PrintLines
Add Edx, Offset PaintArray
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

OK...  Now with your comment (below) to work with, my answer will hopefully be more useful to you, thus I'm completely replacing it with my new answer:

First of all, your PaintArray[] buffer is an array of pointers, not an array of PrintLines objects.  The way you're accessing them (with the -> operator) treats them as pointers, too, so it compiles.  But you're never allocating real PrintLines objects with which to assign to the buffer, thus the NULL you're finding when you break on the vsprintf() call  in your debugger.

It seems to me that there's really no need to dynamically allocate these PrintLines objects, so you could just define PaintArray as an array of PrintLine objects and be done with it (allocation, that is):

```
PrintLines PaintArray[MAX_PRINT_LINES]; // note this is an array of objects, not pointers
```

...but then any time you access them, you need to use the dot-operator, not the arrow-operator.  I don't know if/why you'd need to zero out these objects in your "if (CurrentLine >= MAX_PRINT_LINES)", and I'm not sure what the InvalidateRect() call does for you.  I'm also not sure why you couldn't just have a single global PrintLines object that you keep re-using; won't it be done being used by the time Print() gets called again, or are you running multiple threads?  If you're running multiple threads, then I'm doubtful about the correctness of your "if (CurrentLine >= MAX_PRINT_LINES)" stuff unless you somehow call Print() via some synchronous mechanism & know that all buffered messages are finished being sent by the time you call Print() again.... Will some other code be setting CurrentLine back to zero, or is Print() the only user of the CurrentLine variable?  If Print() is the only user of it, then (1), you could make it a local static variable instead of a global, and (2), I think you have some real correctness issues: either you don't really need an array of these things, or else you shouldn't be clearing them all out when CurrentLine wraps back to 0.

A well-structured non-trivial C++ program will have its components clearly isolated with both a public & private (and protected, if it's in an inheritance hierarchy) interface.  This is accomplished with classes.  Classes are data structures with 'methods' (functions) tied to them.  And things work out really well when you break your code down into small, cohesive units, and build your overall project as a collection of objects that work together, rather than building your project as a monolithic jumble of code.  Coming from an asm background, this is going to be a big leap for you.  I know, I started programming in asm as well... for the Intel 8051, then 8088, then Motorola 68K, and PowerPC 850/860, with a little Sparc thrown in for good measure.  The step from asm to C was minimal, and if you just program in procedural style in C++, that too isn't a big leap, but if you hope to be marketable as a programmer, you really need to take the leap to Object Oriented programming.  Now there are OO zealots that would advocate programming in strictly OO style, but there are also a lot of projects that implement most of their components as objects yet have their main supervisory/control code implemented in procedural code that simply uses the objects... that's probably a really good start, if you can make the leap to doing that.

In that vein, I wrote a version of your code that encapsulates your buffer in a ring buffer class.  This assumes what you actually need is simply a buffer of seemingly never-ending PrintLines objects (never-ending as long as the consumer keeps up so the ring buffer doesn't fill up).  If you're trying to learn C++, I recommend you start encapsulating cohesive concepts as classes, which, once implemented & debugged, help reduce the likelihood of future bugs in other code related to improperly using raw data.  The code below is implemented as a struct with all static data & static methods, which is a little unusual for OO programming, but in this case you'll never need more than one of these "objects" (actually in this case you won't even have a PaintBuffers "object", you just have the class & a bunch of static data & methods).  Some would advocate using a "singleton" pattern for this situation, but that's going over the OO edge and you don't really need that.  This gets you closer to OO thinking and is easier to access (nearly) directly from asm code.  I hope it's useful for you.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdarg.h>

  // ================================== This would go in a .h file.....

  struct PrintLines // My own personal stand-in for whatever a "PrintLines" object is
  {
     int rgb;
     int stringlen;
     char string[400];
  };

  class PaintBuffers // encapsulates a circular buffer of PrintLines objects
  {
  public: // Public data: Anyone can have direct access to this stuff....
     static const unsigned int maxPrintLines = 4; // formerly #define MAX_PRINT_LINES

  private: // Private data: Only this class's methods can access this stuff....
     static PrintLines PaintArray[maxPrintLines]; // note these are real objects, not pointers
     static unsigned int producerIdx; // for data coming into this class
     static unsigned int consumerIdx; // for data going out of this class

  public: // Public methods: Anyone can call these methods....
     static int numUsedBuffers() { return (producerIdx-consumerIdx) % maxPrintLines; }
              // Side note, but important: The % above gives us what we want only if the
              // lhs (left-hand-side) is positive.  One way to ensure that is by simply
              // treating the terms as unsigned; even though subtracting a larger
              // number from a smaller "wraps around" to a very large number, after
              // the % operation we still get what we want, so there's no need to
              // compute the absolute value of a signed subtraction if we just make
              // them unsigned (or cast them as unsigned) in the first place.
  static int numFreeBuffers() { return maxPrintLines - numUsedBuffers(); }

  // Producer calls this: Get the next 'write' buffer (to write into it)
  static PrintLines* getWriteBuf()
     {
        if (numFreeBuffers() > 1) // The >1 implements the "always keep one slot open"
        {                         // solution to the full/empty ambiguity problem, thus
                                // there will ALWAYS be at least one unused buffer.
                                // There are alternative solutions that allow use of
                                // that one last buffer, but none which results in
                                // more efficient code.
           PrintLines* ret = &PaintArray[producerIdx];
           producerIdx = (producerIdx+1) % maxPrintLines;
           // ...Note that if maxPrintLines is a power-of-2 (smart programmers only make
           //    circular buffers that are sized as powers-of-2), the compiler will
           //    automatically turn that % operation into an equivalent & for efficiency.
           return ret;
        }
        else
        {
           return NULL; // Tell the caller there's no more buffer space.
        }
     }

  // Consumer calls this: Get the next 'read' buffer (to read data from it)
  static PrintLines* getReadBuf()
     {
        if (numUsedBuffers() > 0)
        {
           PrintLines* ret = &PaintArray[consumerIdx];
           consumerIdx = (consumerIdx+1) % maxPrintLines;
           return ret;
        }
        else
        {
           return NULL; // Tell the caller there's no data available.
        }
     }
  };

  // Because you can't (easily) call a C++ name-mangled function from assembly,
  // I'll define a "C"-linkage interface to the PaintBuffers class below.  Once
  // your whole ASM project is ported to C++, you can blow the ASM interface away.
  extern "C" int PaintBuffers_numUsedBuffers();
  extern "C" int PaintBuffers_numFreeBuffers();
  extern "C" PrintLines* PaintBuffers_getWriteBuf();
  extern "C" PrintLines* PaintBuffers_getReadBuf();


  // ================================== This would go in a .cpp file.....

  // In the .h file, we declared that there are such functions (somewhere), now
  // we need to actually define them....
  extern "C" int PaintBuffers_numUsedBuffers() { return PaintBuffers::numUsedBuffers(); }
  extern "C" int PaintBuffers_numFreeBuffers() { return PaintBuffers::numFreeBuffers(); }
  extern "C" PrintLines* PaintBuffers_getWriteBuf() { return PaintBuffers::getWriteBuf(); }
  extern "C" PrintLines* PaintBuffers_getReadBuf() { return PaintBuffers::getReadBuf(); }

  // In the .h file, we declared that there are such variables (somewhere), now
  // we need to actually define them....
  PrintLines PaintBuffers::PaintArray[PaintBuffers::maxPrintLines];
  unsigned int PaintBuffers::producerIdx=0;
  unsigned int PaintBuffers::consumerIdx=0;

  // Note that all of the PaintBuffers class's methods were defined inline in the
  // class itself.  You could also just declare them there (in the class definition),
  // and define them here in a .cpp file.


  void Print(/*HWND hWnd,*/ int rgb, const char* string, ...)
  {
     PrintLines* PaintObject = PaintBuffers::getWriteBuf();
     if (!PaintObject) // Is it NULL?
     { // What should we do if there is no more buffer space???
        return; // I guess just do nothing... Lost message.
     }
     // TODO: Is this needed somehow?....  InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
     //  MSG msg;
     va_list argList;
     va_start(argList, string);
     PaintObject->stringlen = vsnprintf(PaintObject->string, sizeof(PaintObject->string)-1, string, argList);
     va_end (argList);
     PaintObject->rgb = rgb;
     //  msg.hwnd = hWnd;
     //  msg.message = WM_PAINT;
     //  DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }


  void Consume() // ...my stand-in for whatever your consumer is (still in ASM?)
  {
     PrintLines* PaintObject = PaintBuffers::getReadBuf();
     if (PaintObject) // Was it non-NULL?
     {
        printf("Consume(): Got \"%s\"\n", PaintObject->string);
     }
     else // This is only here to show that we did get NULL.....
     {
        printf("Consume(): Got NULL! (no buffers with data in them)\n");
     }
  }


  int main()
  {
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dst message.", 1);
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dnd message.", 2);
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Print(0x11111111, "The %drd message.", 3);
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dth message.", 4);
     Consume();
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dth message.", 5);
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dth message.", 6);
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dth message.", 7);
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dth message.", 8);
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dth message.", 9);  // ...will be lost (no more buffer space)
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dth message.", 10); // ...will be lost (no more buffer space)
     Print(0x11111111, "The %dth message.", 11); // ...will be lost (no more buffer space)
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Consume();
     Consume();
  }
```

Comment: i am trying to port the source i made in ASM (MASM) compiler; The idea is to have a buffer of strings that will be readed when a WM_PAINT message gets via DispatchMessage. Problem is if i do it "locally" (stack buffer) the function that process and print the message with TextOut will not have access to the local buffer (since its cleared after the function is over). So i needed a global buffer. Problem is i dont know how to declare an global array of PrintLines Class... or at least get the address of the array position.

Answer (score -1):

ive made a mistake regarding the code of the problem here is the right one:

```
PrintLines *PaintArray[MAX_PRINT_LINES];
int CurrentLine;

void Print(HWND hWnd, int rgb, const char* string, ...)
{
    MSG msg;
    if (CurrentLine >= MAX_PRINT_LINES)
    {
        CurrentLine = 0;
        memset (*PaintArray, NULL, sizeof PaintArray);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, string);
    PaintArray[CurrentLine]->stringlen = vsprintf(PaintArray[CurrentLine]->string, string, argList);
    va_end (argList);
    PaintArray[CurrentLine]->rgb = rgb;
    CurrentLine+=1;
    msg.hwnd = hWnd;
    msg.message = WM_PAINT;
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: Is this the correct working function, or just an "edit" of the code in your question? If it's the correct working function, then you should explain what the problem was, and maybe accept your own answer. If it's just an edit to the code in your question, you should edit your question, and delete this "answer".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - This was an edit of the code in his question.  Yeah, he should have just edited his question & replaced the code.